# Keep original wsdl in jax-ws

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-ws, jax-ws-customization

How can I expose a webservice keeping the original wsdl file?

I have a wsdl file and I generated the stub classes from that file, then I implemented the service, but when I deploy in my Weblogic server, the generated wsdl file is not the same as original wsdl file.

For example, the generated wsdl has different Binding name, Port name, xsd url changed, etc, and I need keep the original wsdl due to client request.

Is possible provide the original wsdl to jax-ws? I tried using the `wsdllocation` property from `WebService` annotation too, but it doesn't works.

Comment: Hard to answer without more implementation details, but what you are looking for is called "contract first" webservices. And normally, wsdl shouldn't be different.

Comment: I'll look for "contract first", thanks

Comment: Did you sort this out?